# R: How can I use a function to create a new dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a data set that I am working with, and trying to use a function to add several descriptive stats of groups in that set to a data frame that I can export as a CSV.

Here is a really simplified data set (df):

```
     Well   Time  Value
1    A01    0     3
2    A01    1     4
3    A01    2     5
4    A02    0     2
5    A02    1     3
6    A02    2     4
```

Essentially what I want to do is pull several values like min and max values for each group (well), and have those be their own lines in a new dataframe. Here is a portion of the code for the function that I have tried so far, but without success. I'm only adding code for finding the min and max to simplify things, but I have about 15 other data points that I am pulling from my complete dataset.

```
# Dataframe to add to
df1 <- (A, 1, 2)
names(df1) <- c("well", "max", "min") # (plus other values)

# Function
stat.well <- function(x = cont_harmless) {
  
  # Vector of names of wells to loop over
  well <- unique(base$Well)
  
  # Loop to create descriptive statistics
  for (i in seq_along(well)) {
    
    # Subset data to single well
    single_well <- x %>% subset(Well == well[i])
    
    # Maximum Value
    a <- max(single_well$TEER)
    b <- which.max(single_well$TEER)
    
    # Minimum Value
    c <- min(single_well$TEER)
    d <- which.min(single_well$TEER)

    # More code for other values
    # More code for other values
    # More code for other values
    # More code for other values
    
    # Add to df1
    df1 %>% add_row(Well = well[i], max = a, min = c)
  }
  Return(df1)
}
   
stat.well()
```

When I run this code, the only return that I get is the data frame from before the function (which is a line that I was planning on taking out). I'm sure this isn't the most elegant solution out there, but I appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that (I think) achieves your desired result. It first groups by the 'Well' column, and then calculates summary stats (min and max) for both the 'Time' and 'Value' columns

```r
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- structure(
  list(
    Well = c("A01", "A01", "A01", "A02", "A02", "A02"),
    Time = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2),
    Value = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-6L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

df %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Time, Value), list(min = min, max = max)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Well  Time_min Time_max Value_min Value_max
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A01          0        2         3         5
#> 2 A02          0        2         2         4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks - this works for finding the min/max of each group and some of the other summary stats, but I still can't use this to solve the other points that I am trying to extract from my dataset. My big issue is just writing the dataframe from the code.

Comment: Then you need to explain these “other points”. I believe @pyg has answered the question(s) for which you provided information.

Comment: Sorry @Limey, I don't think I was clear enough. I just used max and min as an example. In my code, I have the max of the well as object a, and the min as object b. I'm trying to find a way to add those objects to a dataframe with columns "well", "max", and "min" as it loops through all 96 different groups in my full data set. And again, max and min are just fill ins to help solve my problem here.

Comment: @jacobaschi perhaps it would be helpful if you added your desired output to the question, using your simplified dataset as an example. That way we can better understand what you're aiming for.